# Why is the regex "\d+(-\d+)?[A-Z]?" not matching the string "180-186" in a HTML5 pattern attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, validation

I have the following HTML5 form:

```
<form id="address-form" method="POST">
    // ...other inputs that work fine

    <input type="text" name="street_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Street No.*" tabindex="3" required pattern="\d+(-\d+)?[A-Z]?" title="Please enter only digits separated by a single optional hyphen, with a single optional letter suffix.">
    <input type="text" name="street_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address*" tabindex="4" required pattern="[A-z ]+" title="Please enter only letters and spaces.">

    // ...other inputs that work fine
</form>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
let form = $('#address-form');
form.find('[required]').each((i, elem) => {
    invalidElem = $(elem);

    // ...more unrelated code

    if (elem.name === 'password1' && elem.value !== '') {
        password = elem.value;
    }

    if (elem.name === 'password2') {
        elem.setCustomValidity(elem.value === password ? '' :
            'This field must match the password field.');
    }

    invalidElem.removeAttr('style');
    return (isValid = elem.reportValidity());
});
```

I am testing validation of the first input shown with the string "180-186" and it is failing. Why?

According to [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/r/U1scQS/1) this should work fine in JavaScript, which I assume is the regex engine used by browsers to validate `pattern` attributes...but Chrome (at least) seems to disprove that assumption, so if anyone definitively knows the *actual* regex engine used by browsers I'd love to know.

In case it's not obvious to anyone, this input needs to take the street number portion of an address. So "143", "22A", "180-186" and "1-7A" should all match, but having the letter anywhere but the end should **not** match, nor should anything with multiple hyphens, letters or any spaces.

I'd also accept any answer that suggests a reasonable compromise to my strict definition of a house or building number.

Comment: It [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/q8sywedp/), it does not let submitting of invalid values.

Comment: I agree with @WiktorStribiżew - your regex is working fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm, very strange...your JSFiddle indeed works fine, but it's not working on my site...does it make a difference that I'm using [reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) to trigger validation?

Comment: You should add the code to the post so that we could help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that VS Code had simply turned my hyphen into an em dash when I was typing static values into the HTML...d'oh!

Anyway thanks to everyone who commented for trying to help :-)